# I cannot display data via method written by Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

First, I have written `Category` model like below:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
    var status: Short = 0
)

@Dao
interface CategoryDao {
    @Query("SELECT name FROM categories")
    suspend fun getAllCategoryName(): List<String>

    @Query("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = :name")
    suspend fun getIdFromCategoryName(name: String): Int
}

@Database(entities = [Category::class, Product::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun categoryDao(): CategoryDao
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao
}
```

then, I only want to use this `getAllCategoryName()` method to render the `Spinner` component which has id `categoryList` with data like this picture: 
[activity_add_product.xml layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsR80.png)

and here is a `AddProductActivity` class associated with the `activity_add_product.xml` file above:

```kotlin
class AddProductActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddProductBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAddProductBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job()).launch {
            val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "db").build()
            val categories = db.categoryDao()
            val categoryname = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                categories.getAllCategoryName()
            }
            val adapter =
                ArrayAdapter(
                    this@AddProductActivity,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                    categoryname
                )
            binding.categoryList.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, i had record in SQLite:
[SQLite data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI4LA.png) 
I don't know if i was doing wrong somewhere else to display data to `Spinner`. Do you know what is the problem ?
( And last question, maybe I'm dumb but do i need to implement any method inside `CategoryDao` interface anyway ? )

P/s: My English is quite dumb, hope you understand my question.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked printing the data in logs? If the data is received, then it might be some other issue. But if the data is not received from the table then you must check the Room Implementation thoroughly.

If you are obfuscating your code and shrinking it using proguard then you must make changes like this to the name field.

```
@ColumnInfo(name= "name")
var name: String
```

Comment: Do you mean Logcat ? I have never used it any time. But I tried debug instead, it gave me a return result if you choose a breakpoint is the function that retrieves the data I mentioned above which is a string variable but that doesn't seem very useful to me.

Comment: Yes, in Logcat. Add a Log.d(TAG,"$dataToBeCheckedHere")
So that you can see whether the data is fetched from the database or not. 

On the other hand. Where are you populating your database? Do you have a pre-filled data because I didn't find that prepopulating code. Please make sure that your table has the data in it.
You can check your table through App Inspection in Android Studio. Make sure to check the Live Updates On.

Comment: Oh thank you for helped me. I found the error inside my Logcat, it said something like "Did you forget to update the database version after changed the structure of the entities ? ". Then i tried update the database version, after that everything worked as expected. 

Comment: Great! I would appreciate if you can upvote the answer. Thanksss!